# How to convert a list of PyTorch tensors to a list of floats?

Tags: python, list, pytorch, tensor

I have a list of tensors like the following one:

```
[tensor(0.9757), tensor(0.9987), tensor(0.9990), tensor(0.9994), tensor(0.9994)]
```

How can I change the type of the entire list and obtain something like:

```
[0.9757, 0.9987, 0.9990, 0.9994, 0.9994]
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you *also* demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that in my opinion is to include the **text** based version of the source code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right.  If you want a nudge getting started check out `map(float, <your list>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.item()` and a list comprehension, assuming that every element is a one-element tensor:

```py
result = [tensor.item() for tensor in data]
print(type(result[0]))
print(result)
```

This prints the desired result, albeit with some unavoidable precision error:

```py
<class 'float'>
[0.9757000207901001, 0.9987000226974487, 0.9990000128746033, 0.9994000196456909, 0.9994000196456909]
```